# Global Hook for Window creation/maximise/minimise etc in C#

Tags: c#, hook

I want to monitor any window is created globally. The closest API I found is `SetWinEventHook` on `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`, however, it not only hooks window creation but also controls. I wonder if there is any way that does not cost too much, and can hook not only CBT windows.

I tried to use `IsWindow()` to detect if the callback hwnd is a window hwnd, but it seems always return true regardless if the hwnd is a window or control.

I would prefer using managed api rather than adding other dlls, although if it is absolute necessary it is still an open option.

Lastly, how can I hook the windows maximise, minimise and restore events? Tried `EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE` but it seems not the correct one. Tried `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART` and `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND` but also not capturing the max/min/restore events.

Partial code can be seen as follows:

```
private List<IntPtr> _hooks;
private User32ex.WinEventDelegate _delegate;

private void StartService() {
    _delegate = WinEventProc;
    _hooks.Add(User32ex.SetWinEventHook(User32.WindowsEventHookType.EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, User32.WindowsEventHookType.EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, IntPtr.Zero, _delegate, 0, 0, User32.WindowsEventHookFlags.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT));
    // Other hooks
}

private void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, User32.WindowsEventHookType eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime) {
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero || !User32.IsWindow(hwnd)) return;

    switch (eventType) {
        case User32.WindowsEventHookType.EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE:
            Debug.Print($"Create:  {hwnd}");
            // Do something - here captures all objects not only windows but also controls etc
            break;
        case User32.WindowsEventHookType.EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE:
            Debug.Print($"State change: {hwnd}");
            // Do something
            break;
        // Other cases
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You would likely need to check what window styles are applied to the handle.

Comment: The usual answer to a vague question like this is found in the System.Windows.Automation namespace.

Comment: @Lloyd Thanks. Which WS would definitely separate windows and controls? Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry if I made the question vague. I am not a native speaker and tried my best to describe. Would you please give me some suggestions to make this question more clear? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the beautiful world of Windows API! The reason your hook hooks not only "windows", but also "controls" is that in Windows both "windows" and "controls" are just windows. There might be different kinds of windows they might look different and behave differently; controls are just windows with specific looks and specific behaviours.

Since all of them just windows, you can't just hook to "windows" not hooking to "controls" at the same time. However, when you already hooked to one, you may identify if the window you've hooked to is the kind of window you would like to hook. As suggested in the comments, you may use window styles:

```
// this is a pretty crude and basic way to sort out "controls"
BOOL isControl_KindOf = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CHILD;
```

Comment: Thanks. How about MDI Child? Does it also have WS_CHILD?

Comment: I did not remember that, so I had to google msdn. Apparently, you need another expression to identify mdi children windows, that is (GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE_EX) & WS_EX_MDICHILD).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try :)